# By considering the real part of the integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to calculate $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{4 + \sin^2\theta}$$ strictly by considering the real part of the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2 + i\sin\theta}$ which I know to equal $\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt 5}$.

I know the $Real$ part of an integral equals the integral of the $Real$ part, but I can't seem to make any headway into getting the value of this integral from the real part of the given integral. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: The next step is to consider $z=e ^{i\theta}$, then $d\theta=dz/(iz)$ and $2+i\sin\theta=2+z-1/z$, and you are led to evaluate a complex integral of a holomorphic function on the unit circle. Does this ring bells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac 1 {4+\sin^2\theta} = \frac 1 {(2+i\sin\theta)(2-i\sin\theta)} = \frac A {2+i\sin\theta} + \frac B {2-i\sin\theta} 
$$
If you've worked with partial fractions before, then do the same thing here.

And $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2+i\sin\theta}= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2-i\sin\theta}$ since the real parts are same and the imaginary parts are $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance; it was completely oblivious to me to use partial fractions!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The relationship between the functions being integrated is multiplying by the complex conjugate.